# Limiting SSH to SFTP only?

Tags: ssh, sftp, authorized-keys

I use SSH keys to allow passwordless logons to my box. I want to limit them to SFTP only.

I have the following in my `authorized_keys` file which appears to work:

`command="internal-sftp" ssh-rsa ...`

I can't seem to find a way around it...but I am no genius...am I actually secure?

Comment: Do you allow password authentication at all?

Comment: No...nobody knows the password.

Comment: That's not what I asked. In /etc/ssh/sshd_config or equivalent, is `PasswordAuthentication` set to `yes` or to `no`?

Comment: @AaronMiller set to `yes`, but I can set that from the `authorized_keys` file though can't i?

Comment: Doesn't look that way from the documentation, no. I'd turn it off in sshd_config; when you set the forced command in authorized_keys, it applies only to connections authenticated with that key. If you have password authentication enabled, logging in with the password will produce a shell as usual, so (for example) someone who runs a successful dictionary attack can still hose you pretty bad.

Comment: @AaronMiller ah right, that won't be the case with this account as you can only login with the key. Its a passwordless account (in that nobody knows the password)

Comment: Much better methods detailed on SF: http://serverfault.com/q/354615/28549

Answer (score 2):

not really. One can just download the authorized_keys file, edit it removing the command="internal-sftp" part and upload it on top of yours and then ssh into the box.

Comment: Yes, changing the shell is also needed, chroot jail is also a good practice.  And forwarding can be a vulnerability as well.  http://serverfault.com/a/354618/28549

Answer (score 2):

I think the proper way to configure this would be to add `ForceCommand internal-sftp` to the specific user section on `sshd_config`

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match User MyUser
    PasswordAuthentication no
    ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory /home/MyUser
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better also remove the password from the account (no matter that *"nobody knows the password"*).

```
passwd --delete username
```

Other than that your solution seems ok.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer. It already is a passwordless account.

Comment: A passwordless account is an account that doesn't require a password to login. A disable password is a different thing. BE WARNED!